# How can I compare values between two data frame columns based on matching field values?

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`, and want to know if something like the following is (easily) possible:

For every `df1$id` that matches `df2$id`, I want to compare `df1$day` against `df2$day` and either classify them as `MATCH` or `NO MATCH` in a new column (`df1$matched`) depending on whether they are identical or not.

**Further clarification:**

If a value in `df1$id` matches / appears in `df2$id`, I then want to look at `df1$day` and `df2$day` against that particular `id`.  Next, I want to compare the values from `df1$day` and `df2$day` to see if they are the same or different.  I then want to create a new column (`matched`) which classifies these values based on whether or not they are the same.  Thus, for every `id` match between `df1` and `df2`, the algorithm should output something like this:

Sample data:

```
df1$id    df1$day
001       2
002       2
003       8
004       2
005       8
006       8

df2$id    df2$day
004       2
005       2
006       8
007       2
008       8
```

Output:

```
df1$id    df2$id    df1$day    df2$day    df1$match
004       004       2          2          MATCH
005       005       8          2          NO MATCH
006       006       8          8          MATCH
```

Note that the results can be stored in a new data frame; just so long as it presents the data in this way (or something similar) then it's fine.

My first thought was something like this, but it takes a really long time to process (`df1` is 844,000 rows deep and `df2` is 101,610, so not truly enormous data frames) only to ultimately fail, so I have clearly done something wrong:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(id %in% df2$id) %>% 
  mutate(
    matched = if_else(day == df2$day, "MATCH", "NO MATCH")
  )
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should please post a few rows of your data to understand the scenario, actually.  You are comparing one row day with everyother row of df2$day.  Its intention is not clear

Comment: I have added in an example of what the expected output should look like; as the data are confidential, I'm afraid I cannot share actual data.

Comment: Please post a few rows of both datasets instead.  The criteria of matching rows in two dfs is not clear to me

Comment: As mentioned, the data are confidential so I'm afraid I can't just "post a few rows"; if I could, I would.  I believe that I have explained it clearly, but I will reword it to assist you further.

Comment: I have provided a basic version of the data frames and fields that I am using.  The concept is identical so this should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = 'id    day
001       2
002       2
003       8
004       2
005       8
006       8', header = T)

df2 <- read.table(header = T, text = 'id    day
004       2
005       2
006       8
007       2
008       8')

library(dplyr)


df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = 'id') %>%
  mutate(match_yn = c('no_match', 'match')[1 + (day.x == day.y)])
#>   id day.x day.y match_yn
#> 1  4     2     2    match
#> 2  5     8     2 no_match
#> 3  6     8     8    match
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: You can use `if_else(day.x == day.y, "MATCH", "NO MATCH")` instead of `c('no_match', 'match')[1 + (day.x == day.y)]` as well.

Comment: Yes, why not?  Its just actually I didn't wanna make use of ifelse/if_else unnecessarily at least when there are two conditions

Comment: Wonderful solution, thank you. Also, I like your addition, @Tim - I have adapted AnilGoyal's solution to incorporate this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```r
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                      day = c(2, 2, 8, 2, 8, 8)),
                 row.names = c(NA, -6L),
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <- structure(list(id = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
                      day = c(2, 2, 8, 2, 8)),
                 row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

left_join(df1, df2, by = "id", suffix = c("", "_m")) %>%
  transmute(id, day, match = ifelse(is.na(day_m), "NO MATCH", "MATCH"))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     id   day match
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     2 NO MATCH
2     2     2 NO MATCH
3     3     8 NO MATCH
4     4     2 MATCH
5     5     8 MATCH
6     6     8 MATCH
```